# static filtering of a JTree/ multiple Jtrees sharing (the relevant parts of) a model

Tags: java, swing, jtree, defaulttreemodel

I have a Jtree With two top children Say **A** and **B**. Currently the code is designed to show both in the same panel as they are part of a shared JTree. What I want to do is, seperate A and Binto two different panels.

Now, the Jtree has a complicated update system and there are ways of A members automatically entering B, vice versa, etc. and I don't really want to have two seperate JTrees. I know I can access the relevant data using:

```
myTree.getModel().getChild(myTree.getModel().getRoot(),i)
```

but is there a way of displaying **A** and its sub-children in one panel and B in another?

if no, I guess I will have to resort to creating **myTree_A** and **myTree_B** which will track **myTree**. What is the neatest and msot efficient way of doing this?

***Update***:

So I opted for creating two separate trees. I however have a small problem, when I 'root_A.add(A)' and 'root_B.add(B)' in my two new trees, where **root_A** and **root_B** are **myTreeA** and **myTreeB**'s roots respectively, A and B are detached from **myTree**'s root and I can no longer hook the elements of **myTreeA,B** to the original *myTree* and call the relevant routines. Any way of telling **myTreeA** and **myTreeB** to track A and B without deleting their parent? In other words, can I share models/nodes between trees?

Comment: Implement your own [TreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html), which supports filtering

Comment: It's legacy code and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: you can implement your own tree model as a wrapper for the old model, which additionally provides filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The neatest way will be to create two separate trees so that models attach to A and B can be easily updated and reflected easily.

Comment: Why would you like to make myTree as parent of TreeA and TreeB instead of Root_A and Root_B? Also, if you want to share the nodes of TreeA/Tree B with thier root trees and MyTree, then you can visit the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849530/sharing-children-among-parents-in-a-jtree

Comment: I made no mention of a parent-child relationship. I want them to share the same same model as the "parent" tree. That's not exactly the same thing, is it?

Comment: No, that was if you want to share the nodes between trees.and yes you can always share the model between two jtrees. You can have a look at the example shared here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142290/easiest-way-to-clone-a-whole-jtree-treemodel